# How to properly pack a box of pineapples?

Tags: luggage, airlines, alaska-airlines

Alaska Airlines have an [exception to standard baggage charges](https://www.alaskaair.com/content/travel-info/baggage/baggage-fee-waivers-exceptions) for the following item: `Pineapple from Hawaii - one properly packaged box of pineapples when traveling within the United States from Honolulu (HNL), Kona (KOA), Maui (OGG), or Kauai (LIH)`

What does such a box of pineapples look like? Does that only mean that they should not fall out of the box while transported, or are there specific requirements that a properly packaged box must meet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pineapples purchased in Hawaii and packed for transport vary in size from a one-pack to a larger box of 7-9 (depending on size). Here are some packaging examples, borrowed from Maui Gold®:

[image]

[image]

As an agricultural product arriving on the mainland, the [US Department of Agriculture](https://www.aphis.usda.gov/aphis/resources/travelers-int/ct_hawaiian_products) restrictions apply. Fresh pineapple is permitted, but must be presented to the USDA inspector at the airport prior to departure from Hawaii. You can provide your own packaging. Depending on the airport, USDA inspection stations for checked baggage are adjacent to airline check-in counters, and carry on is usually inspected at security check point.

Comment: Interesting, I assumed that when they say "We will transport the following items free of charge and not count them toward your checked baggage allowance", they mean that it will be checked, not a carry on. I added a link to the page in question if you want to take a look. Also, how would one present them to an inspector? Are they in a special office and you have to seek them, or is it part of the "passenger flow" when going through the motions at the airport?

Comment: @JohnEye You're correct on checked baggage. Depending on the airport, the USDA inspection stations for check-in baggage adjacent to the airline check-in counters; carry on is inspected at security.

Comment: But if the airline handles that box like they handle all baggage, all the pineapples will fall out...